# sqlalchemy bulk update fails

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table = foo (minimal example below):

```
house       processed
----------  ----------
95.0
10.0
63.0
6.0
55.0
1.0
19.0
1.0
30.0
21.0
sprite
```

I want to change decimal values to integers and find out when there is a non-numeric value in that column. I have tried with the `query.filter().update()` construct and while that gives me what I want, for 100k rows it takes forever. I understood `bulk_update` can help me. But I might be doing something wrong. My code is:

```
class foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    rowid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    house = Column(Float)
    processed = Column(String(255))

mappings = []
for idx, s in enumerate(session.query(foo), start=1):    
    if type(s.house) in (int, float):
        replace = int(s.house)            
        info = {'processed':replace}
    else:
        info = {'processed':'not number'}        
    mappings.append(info)  
session.bulk_update_mappings(foo, mappings)
session.commit()
```

> mappings [{'processed': 95}, {'processed': 10}, {'processed': 63}, {'processed': 6}, {'processed': 55}, {'processed': 1}, {'processed':
>   19}, {'processed': 1}, {'processed': 30}, {'processed': 21},
>   {'processed': 'not number'}]

This gives me an error:

> UPDATE statement on table 'foo' expected to update 11 row(s); 0 were
>   matched

Full error:

```
session.bulk_update_mappings(foo, mappings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\M64H098\repo\Enrichments-bag\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2868, in bulk_update_mappings
    self._bulk_save_mappings(
  File "C:\Users\M64H098\repo\Enrichments-bag\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2885, in _bulk_save_mappings
    transaction = self.begin(subtransactions=True)
  File "C:\Users\M64H098\repo\Enrichments-bag\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 947, in begin
    self.transaction = self.transaction._begin(nested=nested)
  File "C:\Users\M64H098\repo\Enrichments-bag\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 316, in _begin
    self._assert_active()
  File "C:\Users\M64H098\repo\Enrichments-bag\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 288, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: UPDATE statement on table 'foo' expected to update 11 row(s); 0 were matched. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/7s2a)
```

What can I do to update the `processed` column in-place in bulk with the `mapping` dictionary?

Comment: You need to include the row ids to tell the database which rows to update `[{'id': 42, 'processed': 111}, ...]`

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes! it works, thanks. Could you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bulk_update_mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_update_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings) requires that the primary keys for the rows being updated are included in the update dictionaries.  This makes sense when you think about it - there needs to be a way for the database to identify the rows that must be updated.  In this case, the primary keys would be the `rowid`s of the `Foo` model.

```
info = {'rowid': s.rowid, 'processed':replace}
```

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> a sequence of dictionaries, ... All those keys which are present and are not part of the primary key are applied to the SET clause of the UPDATE statement; **the primary key values, which are required**, are applied to the WHERE clause.